# How to compare all values in one vector to all values in another? (In minimal time)

Tags: r

I have the following r code:

```
list1 <- c(5, 6, 8, 10, 15, 26, 75) 
list2 <- c(3, 6, 8, 10, 100, 42)

total <- length(list1)*length(list2)
  for(x in 1:length(list1)) {
    for(y in 1:length(list2)) {
      print(total - (x*y))
      if(list1[x]>list2[y]) {
        l1Bigger <- l1Bigger + 1
      } else if(list1[x]<list2[y]) {
        l2Bigger <- l2Bigger + 1
      } else {
        tie <- tie + 1
      }
    }
  }
  percents <- c(l1Bigger/total, l2Bigger/total, tie/total)
  return(percents)
```

Basically, what I want my code to do is iterate through list1 and list2 and compare the values to figure out how often the values in list1 are greater than the values in list 2. My current method takes a lot of time, is there any way to reduce the amount of time this process takes?

Thank you!

Comment: If the arguments are vectors then using `list1, list2` is confusing

Comment: @JohnColeman Sorry :(

Comment: @SymbolixAU yeah: list1 <- c(5, 6, 8, 10, 15, 26, 75) list2 <- c(3, 6, 8, 10, 100, 42)

Comment: @RichScriven Thank you, I will try this!!

Comment: No, don't.  That won't work.

Comment: `rowSums(outer(list1, list2, \`>\`))`

Comment: @alistaire I'm working with fairly long lists, does this method take a long time?

Comment: Firstly, what you're showing are vectors, which are not lists (which are something else). `outer` is certainly faster than what you've got, but it's going to create a matrix of the dimensions of each vector, which can take a lot of memory. Ultimately the best answer depends on how long you mean; you could write a very fast Rcpp implementation, but depending on size, there's a good chance it's overkill.

Answer (score 2):

`expand.grid` is a natural way to do this sort of thing:

```
> x <- c(2,4,5,1,3)
> y <- c(1,6,2,3)
> g <- expand.grid(x,y)
> x.bigger <- sum(g$Var1 > g$Var2)
> y.bigger <- sum(g$Var1 < g$Var2)
> ties <- sum(g$Var1 == g$Var2)
> x.bigger
[1] 9
> y.bigger <- sum(g$Var1 < g$Var2)
> ties
[1] 3
```

Of course, `ties` can just be computed via simple arithmetic from the other two values, but I wanted to show how you could get all three numbers directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert what you've got into `Rcpp` which should speed up the process on long vectors

```
library(Rcpp)

set.seed(1)
v1 <- rnorm(10000)
v2 <- rnorm(10000)

cppFunction('NumericVector compareVectors(NumericVector v1, NumericVector v2){

            NumericVector out(3);

            for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++){
               for(int j = 0; j < v2.size(); j++){
                  if(v1[i] == v2[j]){
                     out[0]++;
                  }else if(v1[i] < v2[j]){
                     out[1]++;
                  }else{
                     out[2]++;
                  }
               }
            }
            return out;
        }')

compareVectors(v1, v2)
[1]          0 5008309906 4991690094
```

which shows favourable results when benchmarked

```
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(1)
v1 <- rnorm(1000)
v2 <- rnorm(1000)

microbenchmark(

    rcpp = {
        compareVectors(v1, v2)
    },
    exg = {
        g <- expand.grid(v1, v2)
        x.bigger <- sum(g$Var1 > g$Var2)
        y.bigge <- sum(g$Var1 < g$Var2)
    }
)

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
# rcpp  5.600956  5.788145  6.036816  5.927468  6.183143   8.385282   100
#  exg 28.529272 35.246216 41.328205 36.000421 37.653801 540.850561   100
```